# Javascript - Adding Name/Scores (key/values) of an object within an array to get total scores in a new object with name/score as key/value

Tags: javascript

I've been stuck on this problem for hours, I can't seem to add the scores together and msot of the things I've tried end up giving me NaN or entirely wrong scores.

Example input is:

```
Example 1:
let ppl = [{name: "Anthony", score: 10},
            {name: "Fred", score : 10},
            {name: "Anthony", score: -8},
            {name: "Winnie", score: 12}];
```

My code which is not adding the scores together for multiple entries.

```
function countScores(people) {
  // Your code here

  let scoreCount = {};
  

  people.forEach(person => {  // Go through the people 

    let name = person.name; // Grab the name of the person
    let score = person.score // Grab the score of the person


    if (scoreCount[name]) {  //Check if name exists already and add scores together
      scoreCount[score] += person.score;
      console.log("Am I being accessed???")
    }

    score = Number(person.score);   // Grab the score of person and set it to score
    name = person.name;      // Grab the name of the person
    console.log(name, score);
    
    scoreCount[name] = score;


  })

    console.log(scoreCount)
    console.log("Endig Calculation of Scores....")
    return scoreCount;

};
```

My results are:

```
      + expected - actual

       {
      -  "Anthony": -8
      +  "Anthony": 2
         "Fred": 10
         "Winnie": 12
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below implementation using `reduce()`

```js
let ppl = [{name: "Anthony", score: 10},
            {name: "Fred", score : 10},
            {name: "Anthony", score: -8},
            {name: "Winnie", score: 12}];

function countScores(people) {
 let result = people.reduce((res, record) => {
  if(!res[record.name]) {
    res[record.name] = record.score;
  }else {
   res[record.name] += record.score;
  }
  return res;
 }, {});
 return result;
}


console.log(countScores(ppl));
```

Comment: Works perfectly, I'm homeless and have been trying to do this problem for HOURS like a retard, it's my second day working with objects. I VERY MUCH appreciate your response.

Comment: Great!! that it helped. Please feel free to give an upvote :)

Comment: Absolutely, I did. Howver, my rep is 11 and I need 15 to upvote for it to show publically. I always go the extra mile when someone takes the time to help. Thank you again, I'm homeless so I very much appreciate it. Coding will be my way out of this horror. <3 Have a beautiful night/day/morning

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `reduce()` to do it

```js
let data = [{name: "Anthony", score: 10},
            {name: "Fred", score : 10},
            {name: "Anthony", score: -8},
            {name: "Winnie", score: 12}];
            
let result = data.reduce((a,v) =>{
  let exists = a[v.name]
  if(exists){
    a[v.name] += v.score
   }else{
    a[v.name] = v.score
   }
  return a
},{})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: The guy below beat you to it, however, I very much appreciate your time and response!!